# How to Generate REST full services in WEB API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, routes

When i created one `URL` in `WEB.API` i got something like this

> http://loaclhost/communities?userid=1

but i need something like

> http://loaclhost/communities/1

Is it possible?

> **Update:**

I go the answer thanks to @[midhun-p](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9605487/midhun-p).

Some error handling :

1. Invalid 'WebDAV' module--> Take Help from [HelenaG Grulichova](https://devnet.kentico.com/questions/how-do-you-fix-a-500-server-error-while-running-rest-put-or-delete-requests-).
2. 404 mehtod not foud --> add `routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();` in `RouteConfig.cs`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.Decorate your API method with **HttpGet** Attribute and add **Route** parameter.
Example code below .

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("communities/{userid}")]
    public string communities(int userid)
    {
        //your code
    }
```

you can call this api as **http://loaclhost/api/controllername/communities/1**

Comment: if i'd like to add one more parameter how to add in `Route`?. What we call them [HttpGet], [HttpPost],  [Route("{userid}")], etc., ? annotations or something?

Comment: [HttpGet]
    [Route("communities/{userid}/{anotherValue}")]
    public string communities(int userid,int anotherValue)
    {
        //
    }  you can call this api as http://loaclhost/api/controllername/communities/1/2

Comment: Do we need to add `?` in  [Route("communities/{userid}")] ?

Comment: if the parameter is Nullable then you can add ? else no need

Comment: Oh Great Thanks!!!!!

Comment: welcome .... :)

Answer (score 1):

Using Attribute routing you can decorate the method API  as you wish.

Check the below links.
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/bhushangawale/attribute-based-routing-in-Asp-Net-mvc-5/
https://exceptionnotfound.net/attribute-routing-vs-convention-routing/